# Entity not passed on UpdateAsync

Tags: json, windows-phone-8.1, azure-mobile-services

Currently I can insert and lookup entities perfectly fine, however when I do

```
await myTable.UpdateAsync(entity);
```

It correctly goes into the corresponding TableController but no entities are passed through, every field is null, or its MinValue.

I can put the same entity into an

```
await myTable.InsertAsync(entity);
```

and all variables correctly come through at the other end.

Just to add some more information, I am getting the entity originally by

```
Entity entity = await myTable.LookupAsync(id);
```

Then I update values on this entity and pass it to the UpdateAsync

The Entity definition on my mobile app is

```
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public String firstName { get; set; }

    public String lastName { get; set; }

    public DateTime added { get; set; }

    [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Version]
    public string Version { get; set; }

    public DateTimeOffset CreatedAt { get; set; }

    public DateTimeOffset? UpdatedAt { get; set; }

    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
```

The entity definition is the same at the TableController, the only difference is that I don't specify the CreatedAt, UpdatedAt, Deleted and Version as they are part of EntityData that I am inheriting from.

At the TableController end here is some more information on the patch.

```
patch.GetUnchangedPropertyNames().ToList();
Count = 5
    [0]: "added"
    [1]: "firstName"
    [2]: "lastName"
    [3]: "Version"
    [4]: "CreatedAt"
patch.GetChangedPropertyNames().ToList();
Count = 3
    [0]: "Id"
    [1]: "UpdatedAt"
    [2]: "Deleted"
```

I also tried changing the Id to a string and removing the DateTime at both ends yet the firstName and lastName never come through.

Due to more debugging (as per my comments below) I correct my statement and say that it is at the TableController end. It is not accepting anything other than Booleans.

The dynamic view will show DateTime or Int32 but no String. For example I added an integer property to my entity and sent this through

```
{
   "Deleted":"false",
   "test":123,
   "firstName":"test"
}
```

But here is what I get in the controller.

[image]

Just a note, I can change Deleted to true and it reflects correctly.

Comment: Not sure if this helps but I added a Guid on the test Mobile Service ToDo project, that has a working UpdateAsync. The other details still passed through fine, but the Guid always came through as empty.

Comment: As a first step, can you try hitting your .NET backend table through the help page, fiddler, or postman and see if you see the same issue?  I'd have expected the GUID to throw on the client (the id should only be int or string there currently)

Comment: I will give the help page a go shortly, forgot about that. As for the GUID, that works fine as I am using the SimpleMappedEntityDomainManager

Comment: Ok, the help page doesn't help because it can't automatically generate the required input (designed like that apparently). However what I decided to do is use a tool to simulate REST requests. What I found was interesting. Boolean's come through fine but Strings fail. DateTimes show in the DynamicView but their value is passed. Any string value isn't shown in the DynamicView.

Comment: Tried using [JsonProperty("firstName")] on the properties as well, no luck there.